# Getting to parameters wrong number

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

Can not pass javascript variable to http get request. Here is the block of code that takes the value of select tag and passes it into request in coffeescript:

```
jQuery(document).ready ->
    mktuClassID = $("#mktu_class").val();

    $("#mktu_class").change getClassID = ->
        mktuClassID = $(this).val()

    $("#registration_application_items").tokenInput("/items/" + mktuClassID, {
        crossDomain: false,
        prePopulate: $("#registration_application_items").data("pre"),
        preventDuplicates: true,
        theme: "facebook"
    })
```

it is always sending the same value in mktuClassID variable, however, I see that my value changed in console.log() but it is always passing the same value in tokenInput method.
Here is the log:

```
Processing by MktuItemsController#token_inputs as JSON
Parameters: {"q"=>"2", "class_id"=>"3"}
MktuItem Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "mktu_items".* FROM "mktu_items" WHERE (name like '%2%' AND mktu_class_id = '3')
```

Please help me, how do I should rearrange my code to get it work?

Comment: 7 questions, 0 accepted answers... please go back and accept some prior answers. http://stackoverflow.com/users/533982/dastan-kozhomuratov?tab=questions

Answer (score 0):

Your `ready` handler does three things:

1. Grabs the current value of `#mktu_class` and stores it in `mktuClassID`.
2. Binds a change handler to `#mktu_class` which stores its value in `mktuClassID`.
3. Calls `tokenInput` with a URL of `"/items/" + mktuClassID` where `mktuClassID` is the value from (1).

The result is that your change handler on `#mktu_class` doesn't do anything useful and any changes to `#mktu_class` will be ignored (well, they'll end up in `mktuClassID` but nothing will look at `mktuClassID` so the effect is the same). Perhaps your indentation is off and you really want the `/items` call to be inside the change handler:

```
jQuery(document).ready ->
    mktuClassID = $("#mktu_class").val();

    $("#mktu_class").change getClassID = ->
        mktuClassID = $(this).val()
        $("#registration_application_items").tokenInput("/items/" + mktuClassID, {
            crossDomain: false,
            prePopulate: $("#registration_application_items").data("pre"),
            preventDuplicates: true,
            theme: "facebook"
        })
```

If that's the case, then do away with `mktuClassID` entirely and add a `$('#mktu_class').change()` call to initialize things:

```
jQuery(document).ready ->
    $('#mktu_class').change ->
        mktuClassID = $(this).val()
        $('#registration_application_items').tokenInput('/items/' + encodeURIComponent(mktuClassID), {
            crossDomain: false,
            prePopulate: $('#registration_application_items').data('pre'),
            preventDuplicates: true,
            theme: 'facebook'
        })
    $('#mktu_class').change();
```

And you really should be properly paranoid and encode `mktuClassID` when you put it in a URL so I added an [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) call too.

If you only want to call `tokenInput` the first time that `#mktu_class` changes then bind the change handler with [`one`](http://api.jquery.com/one/):

```
jQuery(document).ready ->
    $('#mktu_class').one 'change', ->
        mktuClassID = $(this).val()
        $('#registration_application_items').tokenInput('/items/' + encodeURIComponent(mktuClassID), {
            crossDomain: false,
            prePopulate: $('#registration_application_items').data('pre'),
            preventDuplicates: true,
            theme: 'facebook'
        })
```

That version would call `tokenInput` only the first time `#mktu_class` changed.

Comment: I have tried the code that you suggest. It does the thing, the mktuClassID variable gets the correct value, but I get another problem. The problem is that tokenInput method puts an input field in my DOM and it does every time when a change handler works.

Comment: @Dastan: I don't know what `tokenInput` is supposed to do. Do you need to call `tokenInput` every time `#mktu_class` changes or just once?

Comment: @Dastan: Then why are you binding a change handler? And if you only want to call `tokenInput` once then how is your current code not working? Are you not initializing `#mktu_class` properly or do you only want to call `tokenInput` the first time it changes?

Comment: I call change handler to get current value of #mktu_class to pass it tokenInput. I thought that mktuClassID variable will get actual value after change handler in tokenInput method, but it doesn't.

Comment: I've found a solution to my problem. Here is it https://github.com/loopj/jquery-tokeninput/pull/77 . We can pass three parameters in source: it can be any local data, URL or function which is dynamically called and should return an url string. It fix the problem. Thanks a lot @mu is too short.